# Searchkick reindex on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I keep getting this error when i deploy to heroku :

```
 Searchkick::MissingIndexError in PostsController#search
Index missing - run Post.reindex
```

It's working in development, but how do I reindex in production? Please include exact steps if possible.

Here is my controller for the reference :

```
def search
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
end
```

Comment: Could you please briefly explain how you setup Searchkick on heroku ? Works in local, but not in production. Do I need the bonsai addon ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick Yeah, install Bonsai Elasticsearch. You can use this link for help: http://danifankhauser.com/post/104137889438/rails-how-to-index-searchkick-on-heroku-with

Comment: Thanks it works with bonsai. But 50$ is crazy expensive for the first plan !! Any alternative for heroku ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick Amazon Elasticsearch is very affordable, around $13 per month, and you have a lot more customizability. It's an extra account/service to set up and maintain, but it all boils down to a few ENV variables in the end and is quick to set up. Interestingly, all the Heroku ES addons are literally just proxies to Amazon ES instances...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay I got it, for the people struggling with this run :

```
heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=PutYourClassHere
```

then

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```